# Why no option to import a WAR file into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, war

I have a WAR file for a Java project but when I try to import it into Eclipse, the only option is for archive files such as tar, zip, jar - nothing for war.

Is this only an option in certain editions of Eclipse because I have a copy of SpringSource (also Eclipse-base) that allows me to import WAR files?

**Would it be possible to add this option to my current version without downloading a new edition of Eclipse?**

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your version of Eclipse is **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers**. Try download **Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers**

Your version of Eclipse doesn't have the `Web` tree pane.

Answer (score 3):

What version of eclipse do you have? I have 3.4 and 3.5 installed currently and both have this following path to import a war file.

Go to File->Import->Web->War.

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot I posted above, there is no File->Import->Web->War option. I'm using Ganymede (3.52).

Comment: Okay, The Elite Gentleman mentioned you must not have Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers. My Eclipse 3.5 is for EE developers. WAR is part of dynamic web project stuff so you really need the EE version. You can download it from here http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ .

Comment: I said, you need Eclipse IDE for Jave EE Developers.

Comment: I can import WAR files with my Eclipse. Sorry I am not following what you said. I am using eclipse galelio and I can import file following the path I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If u still using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers so there is a alternate solution for it, it is not a good solution for developer but it work.

1.Unzip the war file.

2.than create a project in eclipse.

3.Than copy the contain of unzip folder one by one & paste in proper position in your project.like servlet paste in src & jsp pages place in war folder.

4.care fully read this point
an unzip folder there is a web-inf folder & also in your project there is web-inf folder. So copy the contain of web-inf folder carefully in project web-inf folder.

This solution perfectly work.

Answer (score 1):

Just install the Eclipse Web Dev tools from the Marketplace over the Eclipse for Java developers. No need to install IDE for Java EE developers.