# Import WAR file does not work properly - Creates duplicates

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

For my graduate project, our professor has given us an existing piece of code, which is Java EE, The servlets are in `<PROJECT_NAME>/servlets`, and other java resources are in `<PROJECT_NAME>/src`.

Professor has given us a WAR file, when I import the project as a WAR file, eclipse ends up creating multiple copies of the servlets and other java files as well, once in the `<PROJECT_NAME>/` and again in `<PROJECT_NAME>/WebContent`

Why is this happening? If I import the project with "Import Existing Projects", it imports fine, but then it does not work with Apache Tomcat, and gives me the error "Resource not available". How do I fix this??

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Related posts, http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwimpwar.htmland  this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11465320/1793718 and