# Importing war file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a WAR file with Java codebase. I need to decompile my war to a project in  Eclipse

To do that I install Eclipse Jee 2018-12 and I had clicked in `File->import` and I selected warFile, and I put my file war

but I have this when I go to src to see code java I have just package 
[image]

When I click in `open type hiererchy`  i have this

[image]

How I can get source file content?

Comment: a war file is a packed file, not as much a compiled file. you can just unzip it. it's .class files that can be decompiled

Comment: Decompiling has nothing to do with WAR/JAR file. WAR file is just like a zipped file. Decompiling is about reversing .class files.

Comment: How i can do it please

Comment: You can do a search in any search engine. The question, as it is now, too broad (We are not going to give you a tutorial on this).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why no option to import a WAR file into Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513284/why-no-option-to-import-a-war-file-into-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

i always prefer to do it outside eclipse. its pretty easy if you just want to view the code.

you can use tools like [jdecompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) . just select/open you war file.

Comment: How i can do it please have an tuto to do that please

Comment: if you go the website they have some screen shots on how to do it. i also there is a plugin available for eclipse.